# Gulp-watch: Problem monitoring all files of an extension

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

guys.

I'm having a problem using gulp-watch. I can only monitor a file specifically expressing it's name, like this:

```
function monitorFiles(cb){
   watch('fakemessage/whatsapp/whatsapp.html', () => gulp.series(waAppHTML)())
}
```

If I want to watch every html file, it doesn't work, like this:

```
function monitorFiles(cb){
   watch('fakemessage/whatsapp/*.html', () => gulp.series(waAppHTML)())
}
```

I would like to monitor all files with the extension html on that folder. Can anyone help me with what I'm doing wrong?

Versions:
"gulp": "^4.0.2"
"gulp-watch": "^5.0.1"